# Blender/Buffergeometry—access vertices from vertex group

Tags: three.js

I have made a Mesh with blender which has a named, non-empty, vertex-group attached to it. To export everything properly, using the three blender exporter, I chose to export »BufferGeometry« and added a »*« to the extra vertex groups field (see screenshot below)…

[image: screenshot blender export three]

This works quite well and generates a working mesh and geometry after import. **But** there are two things that I do not understand:

FIRST:

```
let vertices  = this[DISK]geometry.getAttribute('position');    
vertices.count / 3; // 226 -- Blender (edit mode vertices) 282
vertices.itemSize   // 3   -- one for x, y and z each, as expected
```

So why are there fewer Vertices in the exported model?

SECOND:

When accessing the vertex group like this:

```
let hole = this[DISK]geometry.getAttribute('hole');
hole.count/3;  // 226 (same number of items as vertices) why not a third?
hole.itemSize; // 1 -- why?

let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < hole.count; i += hole.itemSize) {
    let value = hole.array[i]; // either 1 or 0

    if (value > 0) count++;
}

console.log(count); // 148 (148/3 = 49.333333) ??????
```

Does this mean: if `value > 0` the vertex:

```
(vertices.array[i], vertices.array[i+1], vertices.array[i+2])
```

is included in the group? What does a positive value mean?

Thanks in ahead!

**UPDATE**

Crawling the exporter's source on github led me to [Lines 247 - 265 of `utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/exporter/api/mesh.py`.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/exporter/api/mesh.py#L247) So the routine iterates all vertices of all faces and then **over all groups** of this vertex. In case the found group index matches the the group to export, the groups' vertex weight is appended to the list **otherwise zero**.

**UPDATE #2**

After some more testing with simpler geometry (a plane) and a smaller vertex group (one item) it was more easy to see how the data is created. Getting the vertices looks like this:

```
let vertices = geometry.getAttribute('position'),
    group = geometry.getAttribute('groupname');

for (let i = 0, n = group.count; i < n; i++) {
    if (group.array[i] > 0) {
        let { x, y, z } = [vertices.getX(i), 
                           vertices.getY(i), 
                           vertices.getZ(i)];
    }
}
```

Much easier than it seems at first. So my what i have learned with this and recommendation for everybody fiddling around with stuff like that: Don't start with complex models, use the smallest amount of vertices, than even those optimizations wont bother!

Comment: for the first part - positions count does not always equal vertex count - if you have indexed geometry(= has "index" attribute) some vertices can be reused

Comment: does this mean that there are doubles in the geometry?

Comment: yes, when you have for example a rectangle, it can consist of two triangles but only 4 vertices because 2 of them get reused for both trianles, just compare positions.count and index.count